# I have a html form with checkbox. I want to call a function written in php, when checkbox is clicked? Can any1 suggest?

Tags: php, html

The php code is: On clicking checkbox. the below function should run

```
 <?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
  {
    function addStudentToHostel()
    {
        $barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
        $student = $_POST['studentname'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobilenumber'];
        $roll = $_POST['rollnumber'];
        $course = $_POST['courseid'];
        $stream = $_POST['stream'];
        echo $barcode."  ".$student;

        $hostelStudentTable = "hostelstudentstable";
        // function to add student to hostel table in database
    }
  }
 ?>
```

After filling the input fields, On clicking the checkbox in html, the function addStudentToHostel() written in php should be executed. This function saves data to a database table. I don't have any idea how to solve it. I am new to php.

The html code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
</head>
<body>
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
    <label for = "brcdnm">Barcode Number</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "brcdnm" name = "barcode" /><br><br>
    <label for = "stunm">Student Name</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "stunm" name = "studentname" /><br><br>
    <label for = "mobnm">Mobile Number</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "mobnm" name = "mobilenumber" /><br><br>
    <label for = "rlnm">Roll Number</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "rlnm" name = "rollnumber" /><br><br>
    <label for = "crsid">Course Id</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "crsid" name = "courseid" /><br><br>
    <label for = "strm">Stream</label>
    <input type = "text" id = "strm" name = "stream" /><br><br>               
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "checkstudent" name = "hostelStudent" />
    <label for = "checkstudent">Add Student To Hostel</label>
</form>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: This `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"` tells the browser which script file to load when the form submit button is pressed. You cannot make it run a function, only a complete script file.

Comment: using a checkbox instead of a button or input type submit, wont submit the form. change that then server side remove the code out of the function (its not needed) or actually call the function. you will then see the `echo $barcode."  ".$student;` echo out

Comment: Of course if you were to add a call to that function into that script it would run that function

Comment: You have to use javascript with an event listener on the checkox. The javascipt then call with AJAX PHP and change the DOM if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Ajax to accomplish that.

Check the checkbox when it changes and call a ajax that will execute your php function.

In short you need to use javascript to do an ajax request in the background to save the information in the database.

Comment: what javascript code should i use? Please tell me.